# RabbitMQ queue with invalid characters won't be deleted

Tags: php, rabbitmq

There is a queue in RabbitMQ which has invalid characters in it's name.
it supposed to be a date. I'm using php:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

And I don't know why it has server's ip in the beginning of it's name, but that doesn't matter.

the main problem is that when I click on delete button in RabbitMQ Management nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use reset option, because I don't want to reconfigure everything again.

Comment: Can you delete that queue from application using the same code for naming you use to declare queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
To remove only queues and not everything do as following:

1. Stop the RabbitMQ service:

   rabbitmqctl.bat stop_service
2. Go to the directory of the RabbitMQ database:

   i.e: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@WIN-H08RRF5OQGI-mnesia
3. Delete two files:

   rabbit_durable_queue.DCD
   rabbit_durable_route.DCD
4. Start the RabbitMQ service:

   rabbitmqctl.bat start_service

Done.

This way everything remains the same, even exchanges. Only queues will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove queue using RabbitMQ API, open terminal and run:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -XDELETE http://localhost:15672/api/queues/test/your_queue_name
```

Comment: I'm using windows server, it doesn't have such command as "curl" and by running it through php, it says "Could not open input file: curl"